# Como ignorar os valores NA em um dataframe ao roda o auto.arima

Tags: r

Tenho o código para rodar o auto.arima em um dataframe pequeno, porém, em algumas colunas tenho vários valores 'NA' (vão de 1990 até 2003, por exemplo). Como estabelecer no meu código que os tais valores sejam ignorados?
>

```
bra.ts <- ts(CSV_BRA, frequency = 1, start = c(1990), end = c(2016))

taxa <- ts(BRA$TX_CS, frequency = 1, start = c(1990), end = c(2016))
# Comando para indicar a regressão

covariates <- c('RURAL', 'AMZ', 'N', "VALUE_N", 'AREA')

fit<- auto.arima(bra.ts[,"TX_CS"], xreg = bra.ts[,covariates], stepwise = FALSE, 
                 approximation = FALSE)
fit
```

> DATAFRAME

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14YjSAAHul9YrBDfs1FoE50mNfA7ftHD6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A função `na.omit(dataframe)` fará a omissão dessas observações.

Comment: Por favor edite a pergunta com a saída de `dput(head(CSV_BRA, 5))`. Dados como imagens não podem ser usados por quem quer ajudar, não podem ser copiados para uma sessão do R.

Comment: Outra maneira é `bra.ts2 <- bra.ts[complete.cases(bra.ts), ]`.